# Bloc Provider error when pop back just for 1 second

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a profile page where I can click on the image to navigate to the edit page. And all are working perfectly working fine with bloc state management. But when pop back to the profile page there is a bloc provider not found error just for some milliseconds. What will be the problem? I researched everywhere, I couldn't find anything. I am providing the screen recording of it.

link to the video : https://youtube.com/shorts/Zr6u-AIcq5I?feature=share

Comment: Where u define the bloc-provider?
in any case, you could wrap your main widget (that you've passed it to `runApp` at main.dart) with bloc-provided. 
Which actually would make your provider accessible to each page(for context).

Comment: Actually I have a bottom navigation bar and 3 pages. So, I wrapped bottomNavigation bar with the bloc and pass the blocprovider.value to 3 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by wrapping the BlocProvider to the MaterialApp.